# How to get results onPostExcute in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I've been using AsyncTask for few days. My old code works on API 8 with runOnUIThred which dosn't work on >API 18. I want to send data to DB with JSON in doInBackground() and get data in onPostExecute(). How do I separate my code into 2 parts?

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       //bla-bla-bla
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
               int success = 0;
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return success;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
          pDialog.dismiss();
          JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); 
          JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

          if (success == 1) {

                txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
                txtCurrent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurrent);
                txtTurn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTurn);

                txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                txtCurrent.setText(product.getString("current"));
                txtTurn.setText(product.getString("turn"));

          }else{ }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You could let `doInBackground` return `JSONObject json` and use it in `onPostExecute`.

Then to check if it was all ok, do the check inside `onPostExecute`.

Something like:

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //bla-bla-bla
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_product_detials, "GET", params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (json == null) return; // check if json is null too! if null something went wrong (handle it, i used return as example)

        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);;

        if (success == 1) {
            JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            txtCurrent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurrent);
            txtTurn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTurn);

            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
            txtCurrent.setText(product.getString("current"));
            txtTurn.setText(product.getString("turn"));

        }else{

        }
    }
```

Comment: int success = json.getInt("TAG_SUCCESS"); after this all Tag Strings become wrong

Comment: int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); without the quotes

Comment: Java will ask to you to catch all checked exception... what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, when I delete extra ; after int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);; there are errors in rows  JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
         JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);  txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
             txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
             txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
             txtCurrent.setText(product.getString("current"));
             txtTurn.setText(product.getString("turn"));

Comment: User: I changed your code and add try/catch onPostExcute. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here you should not use AsyncTask ,try this library----[android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/),which use by Instagram , Pinterest and other famous Android app.With this library,you could complete your work like this:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("username", "james");
params.put("password", "123456");
params.put("email", "my@email.com");
params.put("profile_picture", new File("pic.jpg")); // Upload a File
params.put("profile_picture2", someInputStream); // Upload an InputStream
params.put("profile_picture3", new ByteArrayInputStream(someBytes)); // Upload some bytes
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("http://youdomain.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // Do something here or change your ui according the result.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Java offers interfaces, which are are powerful to add behaviors to your class, in your case you want the AsyncTask subclass to 1-retreive data and 2-store in db, which can be done on your background thread with no problem. and your Activity to update its UI, so you have three behaviors and your problem is in the third behavior, you can overcome this problem easily with an interface.

UIUpdate.java

```
public interface UIUpdate
{
    public void updateFields(JSONObject json);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements UIUpdate
{
    public void execute()
    {
         new GetProductDetails(this).execute("args"); 
    }
    ....
    @override
    public void updateFields(JSONObject json)
    {
            JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            txtPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            txtCurrent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurrent);
            txtTurn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTurn);
            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
            txtCurrent.setText(product.getString("current"));
            txtTurn.setText(product.getString("turn"));
    }
}
```

GetProductDetails.java

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{
    UIUpdate listener;

    public GetProductDetails( UIUpdate listener )
    {
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_product_detials, "GET", params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (json == null) return; // check if json is null too! if null something went wrong (handle it, i used return as example)
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1)
        {
            listener.updateFields(json);
        }
        else{ }
    }
}
```

Also you need to retrun JSONObject from doInBackGround() to use in postExecute().